# Not getting custom field on Add Contact Roles

Tags: lightning, sales-cloud, opportunitycontactrole

I need one help.I have a custom field in Opportunity Contact Role.
But after clicking on Add Contact Roles, we are not getting the custom field.
Can you please help how can I add the field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite doable (in Lightning only). When editing the OCR page layout, you have to edit the Multi-Line Layout, not the layout for the OCR detail page.  This is covered in a [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351206&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  Community best practice is to mark answers as accepted if they do in fact, guide you to a solution.  This way others know the answer "works"

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields are not available sadly.

[image]